# Why does rails give me an error when I try to use match in routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this line in my routes.rb  `match 'calculate' => 'index#calculate'`
And it gives me an error when trying to load the index page:

> You should not use the `match` method in your router without
>   specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both
>   GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose
>   your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match
>   "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"

Basicly it's a simple app that gets a number from a form and then it should print it after doing some calculations with it. But I am stuck with this error now...

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this error replace your `match` statement with a `get` statement

```
Replace:

match 'calculate' => 'index#calculate'

With:

get 'calculate' => 'index#calculate'
```

The reason for Rails suggesting that you use `get` instead of the more generic `match` is improving security by forcing you to make a conscious api design decision. A GET request is different from a POST request. A POST means 'change'; that request changes something, it modifies the system. A GET means 'give this page'. It does not change anything.

I assume your endpoint returns the result of some sort of calculation. You may argue that since the calculation does not change anything, a GET request is the way to go. You can also argue that this endpoint won't always return the same value for the same input (maybe?) in that case you may want to say that this is a POST, since you are not getting a unique resource.

I believe this is test app that you are making. Depending on what aspect of rails do you want to focus your learning on you may want to choose one, implement both and see what changes, or just flip a coin :)

The `match` method used to work in the way you used it, but since rails 4 this was changed to require this explicitness.

Docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints

Comment: Thank you for the helpful reply. I will try to work on from here :)

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown in Rails 4 because using match opens up a route for cross site scripting (XSS) if not very careful. It is hard to tell from your description which routes you actually need, but if you are submitting a form, you most likely just want a get route for initially loading the form and a post route as a location for the form data to be sent do.

To fix this error, simply follow the instructions the error message gives and either use:

```
match 'calculate' => 'index#calculate', via: [:get, :post]
```

or

```
get 'calculate' => 'index#calculate'
```

depending on which routes you need.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
match 'calculate', :to => 'index#calculate'
```

This will create both GET and POST routes. There's no need to use "match" unless you need both. What you're trying to do probably just needs a GET route:

```
get 'calculate' => 'index#calculate'
```